# jquery serialization error: error when parsing date field

Tags: jquery, python, flask, wtforms

I am getting this error message when I try to parse a date field data in python

```
ValueError: unknown string format
```

this is the script in question

```
start_date = parse(contract_dict['start_date'])
```

but the problem is in the serialized data i received from my form
this is how it looks in the server side

```
start_date:04%2F07%2F2014
```

this is how i am sending it to server

```
var url =  flask_util.url_for('save_contract' ,{ contract_str:$( "#rate_input_form"  ).serialize()});
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: using `flask-wtf` would probably make your life easier

Comment: could you please elaborate on your thought

Comment: if you just make a model like `class YourForm(Form): rate = DateTimeField()`, then it handles these kind of things for you. I found [this tutorial](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to#first-form) very helpful